# My azure website sometimes fail Facebook log in but can't know the reason

Tags: facebook, authentication, owin, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm using Azure Websites service for my web project.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and now using ConfigureAuth method.

```
        FacebookAuthenticationOptions opt = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = CodeHelper.FbAppId,
            AppSecret = CodeHelper.FbAppSecret
        };

        opt.Scope.Add("email,publish_stream");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(opt);
```

I'm using the same codes for other projects on common IIS server, they always works well.

But on Azure website, when users try to log in with Facebook, it sometimes works and sometimes fail.

Is there anyone has same experience and got solution?

[2014. 10. 24 - added]

The request has cookies.

```
ARRAffinity=2f93765894d1796d0e56ae32b4e3eed12fa5f132f1866dcd0de7e74c9ac623d2;
__RequestVerificationToken=ou0dasfT-sfeIOE6iorrpaq3BhYTU4msV5mHqkE49PeRA5H3pMkjFg4bqXXpKtMRkhDRB69Rp----AbJSgfWdDoQ2aGbqImRF9Hg3dWHxrw1;
.AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=pFlBijSiTSofAUMCBLIal9GomTD7fqLdh7yWiHRbEaE
```

But /Account/ExternalLoginCallback fails.

Ref.

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.2
[image: DLL Version]
[image: Visual Studio Version]
[image: Fiddler Data]

Comment: Facebook returns our request to ourdomain.com/Account/Login#_=_ but I expect ourdomain.com/#_=_.

Answer (score 1):

Can you, please, check the the Site Url in facebook app setting in developer.facebook.com. And also can you please make sure the redirect_uri on OAuth request is the correct one. 
It would be great if you can share fiddler session (pls do not forget to remove the secrets)

Comment: Thanks, you can download Fiddler log from this url. edkim.co/buildupware.com_login_issue.zip

Comment: For the given version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, the default redirect_uri is "/signin-facebook". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.facebook.facebookauthenticationoptions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx